# Fastlane gym failed Exit status: 1 although Archive Succeeded

Tags: ios, automation, fastlane

I'm using gitLab Runner and the same lane are working fine on another machine I'm making sure of provisioning profile using match and same applleID.

***Yml file***

```
build_mySharp_debug:
  stage: build
  script:
    - fastlane match development
    - fastlane build_target target:$MYSHARP_TARGET_NAME identifier:$MYSHARP_TARGET_ID
  except:
    - staging
    - production
    - deploy_brokers
  tags: 
       - trufla-ios
```

***FastFile build target lane***

```
lane :build_target do |options|
register_devices(devices_file: "fastlane/devices.txt")

 gym(
   scheme: options[:target],
   clean: true,
   silent: true,
   skip_package_ipa: true,
   export_method: "development",
    export_options: {
  provisioningProfiles: { 
    "bundelID" => "match Development BundelID"
  }
},
   configuration: "Debug",
   clean:true
 )

end
```

**output log**

```
4071 ▸ Touching MyProject.app.dSYM
4072 ▸ Archive Succeeded
4073 [02:42:36]: Exit status: 1
4127 [02:42:36]: fastlane finished with errors
28 [!] Error building the application - see the log above
4131 ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
4091 [02:42:36]: Your `export_method` in gym is defined as `development`
4092 [02:42:36]: which might cause problems when signing your application
4093 [02:42:36]: Are you sure want to build and export for development?
4094 [02:42:36]: Please make sure to define the correct export methods when calling
4095 [02:42:36]: gym in your Fastfile or from the command line
4096 [02:42:36]: 
4097 [02:42:36]: 
4098 [02:42:36]: Looks like fastlane ran into a build/archive error with your project
4099 [02:42:36]: It's hard to tell what's causing the error, so we wrote some guides on how
4100 [02:42:36]: to troubleshoot build and signing issues: https://docs.fastlane.tools/codesigning/getting-started/
4101 [02:42:36]: Before submitting an issue on GitHub, please follow the guide above and make
4102 [02:42:36]: sure your project is set up correctly.
4103 [02:42:36]: fastlane uses `xcodebuild` commands to generate your binary, you can see the
4104 [02:42:36]: the full commands printed out in yellow in the above log.
4105 [02:42:36]: Make sure to inspect the output above, as usually you'll find more error information there
```

I'm sure that certificates and provisioning profile is installed and added to the project can anyone give me a hint for what can cause this issue

Comment: Is that the full log? It looks like some parts are missing.

Comment: Thanks @LyndseyFerguson  it was a writing permission with Catalina as gym couldn’t write to log file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that Fastlane and gym did not have write permissions for gym's log directory.

```
~/Library/Logs/gym
```